# Did Dumbledore mend Hagrid's wand with the Elder Wand?

Tags: harry-potter

We all know that Hagrid got expelled because he got framed of the murder of Moaning Myrtle, real name Myrtle Warren, and that got his wand snapped in half.

But we also that Dumbledore was the master of the Elder Wand sometime after that since his expulsion was in 1943, and Dumbledore defeated Grindelwald in 1945.

So did Dumbledore fix Hagrid's wand when he became Headmaster?

Comment: Possible dupe of [Why did Hagrid's umbrella work for him?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9666/why-did-hagrids-umbrella-work-for-him/9667#9667)

Comment: @Valorum do you seriously think an answer of "I have no canon source but maybe X happened" is an answer justifying closing "did X happen"?

Comment: @Kevin the answer to Valorum's linked question says nothing of Dumbledore fixing it, so I don't think your comment is what's happening. And since Hagrid's umbrella is the only wand we see him use, I agree that it's a possible dupe-- if that's what OP is asking about.

Comment: What I meant is that the linked question deals with *all* the possible reasons why Hagrid's wand might still work. The short answer is that we simply don't know, which itself is covered in the other question.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet Valorum's comment linked to a specific answer, which *does* say Dumbledore might have fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Hagrid's wand was not fixed. Hagrid's spells normally did not work out well.

> Hagrid looked down at his umbrella and stroked his beard.
>
> “Shouldn’ta lost me temper,” he said ruefully, “**but it didn’t work anyway. Meant ter turn him into a pig**, but I suppose he was so much like a pig anyway there wasn’t much left ter do.”
>
> <sub><sup>***Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, Chapter 4, The Keeper of the Keys***</sup></sub>

Broken wand can be used for casting spells, but there is no guarantee that it will work. In fact, Hagrid does mention that he still has pieces of his wand and the fact that he uses his umbrella for performing spell is an indication that the broken pieces of the wand is inside his umbrella.

> “Good wand, that one. But I suppose they snapped it in half when you got expelled?” said Mr. Ollivander, suddenly stern.
>
> “Er — yes, they did, yes,” said Hagrid, shuffling his feet. “**I’ve still got the pieces, though,**” he added brightly.
>
> **“But you don’t use them?” said Mr. Ollivander sharply.**
>
> “Oh, no, sir,” said Hagrid quickly. **Harry noticed he gripped his pink umbrella very tightly as he spoke.**
>
> <sub><sup>***Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, Chapter 5, Diagon Alley***</sup></sub>

We see Ron using his broken wand through out Chamber of Secrets with limited success.

> “Ron was having far worse problems. **He had patched up his wand with some borrowed Spellotape, but it seemed to be damaged beyond repair. It kept crackling and sparking at odd moments, and every time Ron tried to transfigure his beetle it engulfed him in thick gray smoke that smelled of rotten eggs.** Unable to see what he was doing, Ron accidentally squashed his beetle with his elbow and had to ask for a new one. Professor McGonagall wasn’t pleased.”
>
> <sub><sup>***Harry Potter and The Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 6, Gilderoy Lockhart***</sup></sub>

Comment: But doesn't Hagrid cite his own lack of schooling as the reason why it didn't work?

Comment: @ibid That can also be the reason for his spell not working but it did not stop him from doing magic, which makes me think his wand was the problem.

Comment: He does a pretty impressive Aguamenti charm in book six.